# Canvas is Blank After Making Draw() Calls

Tags: android, canvas, draw, android-drawable, android-bitmap

Following up with my problem I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58966338/android-best-way-to-programmatically-make-an-image-and-save-it-to-a-bitmap?noredirect=1#comment104187631_58966338) i'm trying to draw some shapes to a canvas that isn't associated with any view/layout (it's totally in memory & never drawn to the screen) and then use the bitmap I drew in my activity.

The problem:
It seems like my draw method never gets called. I have some log messages within it and I never see them print, and when I view the bitmap during runtime in Android Studio's debugger its always blank.

I've read [various posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056331/android-custom-layout-ondraw-never-gets-called) about having to call setWillNotDraw(false) to get the onDraw() method in a custom view to trigger, but because i'm never going to render this canvas to the screen my custom class extends `Drawable()` instead of `View(context` which doesn't include that method. This seems like a good choice since `View` includes lots of logic for user touches and other actions that my no-UI, background-generated drawable won't use.

That being said I still only saw blank bitmaps and no log messages from `onDraw()` when I extended `View` instead of `Drawable` and called `setWillNowDraw(false)` in the classes' constructor.

What's causing my canvas to always be blank?

```
class CustomImage : Drawable() {
    var bitmap: Bitmap

    private var barcodeText = Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        color = Color.BLACK
        textSize = 24f
    }
    private var circlePainter = Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        color = Color.WHITE
    }

    init {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(LABEL_SIDE_LENGTH, LABEL_SIDE_LENGTH, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        Timber.d("canvas: In draw")
        canvas.setBitmap(bitmap)
        canvas.apply {
            drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
            drawText("002098613", LABEL_SIDE_LENGTH - 50f, 50f, barcodeText)
            drawCircle(200f, 200f, 100f, circlePainter)
        }
        Timber.d("canvas: $canvas")
    }

    override fun setAlpha(alpha: Int) {
    }

    override fun getOpacity(): Int {
        return PixelFormat.OPAQUE
    }

    override fun setColorFilter(colorFilter: ColorFilter?) {
    }

    companion object {
        const val LABEL_SIDE_LENGTH = 1160
    }
}


class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity(){
    private lateinit var customImgBitmap: Bitmap

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        customImgBitmap = createImgBitmap()
        val test = POLabelGenerator
    }
    ...
    private fun createImgBitmap(): Bitmap {
        return CustomImage.bitmap
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless that `Drawable` gets set on an onscreen `View`, its `draw()` method never will be called. You don't need to extend any class to create that image. All you need is your own `Bitmap`, `Canvas`, and `Paint`s. First, set up your `Paint`s, then `val bitmap = Bitmap.create(...)`, then `val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)`, then `drawColor()`, `drawText()`, and `drawCircle()`, all right in a row. Your image will then be in `bitmap`. You could stick that all into a single little helper method.

Comment: @MikeM. Ah I didn't realize I could use an instance of canvas outside the scope of draw(). This solution worked, please submit it as an answer and i'll accept it. Thanks!